# Named Credentials with OAuth getting AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE Message on Save

Tags: apex, oauth2, authentication, namedcredentials, authorization

Getting Following error when i tried to save `Named Credential` with OAuth 2.0 `Authentication Protocol`

**Named Credentials:**
[image]

```
{
"name": "AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE",
"message": "Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.",
"links": [
{
"href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error",
"rel": "information_link"
}
]
}
```

`Authentication Provider` Configuration screenshot attached below.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the `Authorize Endpoint URL` in the Auth Provider Settings should be in the format `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/connect?flowEntry=static&client_id=[client id]&scope=[list of scopes]&redirect_uri=[return URL]` (according to the paypal developer documentation here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/integrate/#4-build-the-button). I'm assuming that you don't need to specify the client ID and redirect Uri query parameters, but watch out for the scope parameter.

Comment: tried by adding `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/connect?flowEntry=static`in `Authorize Endpoint URL` and called `https://safarikid-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/auth/test/PayPal` getting error message

Comment: Error Message: `Sorry about that
Looks like this action is not supported. Please return and report this error so that we can support it in the future. (invalid client_id or redirect_uri)`

Comment: Have you tried the auth endpoint url with other parameters (clientID, scope and redirect_uri)?

Comment: You should first try to get this whole scheme working outside of Salesforce with your favorite REST client, then port it to Apex and finally give Named Credentials a shot.